# Livelock or a Deadlock?

Tags: java, multithreading, livelock

I'm preparing for Java SE 7 Programmer II exam. In one of the mock exams there was an exercise to name from what threading problem does the code suffer. This is the code:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Counter obj1 = new Counter("obj1");
        final Counter obj2 = new Counter("obj2");

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Thread.currentThread().setName("first");
                obj1.display(obj2);
            }
        }).start();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Thread.currentThread().setName("second");
                obj2.display(obj1);
            }
        }).start();
    }
}

class Counter extends Thread {
    int i = 10;
    String name;

    public Counter(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public synchronized void display(Counter obj) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5);
            obj.increment(this);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void increment(Counter obj) {
        System.out.println(++i);
    }
}
```

They say it is a livelock. I cannot see it. Please can someone explain it in more detail.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't qualify this as *livelock* based on Wikipedia's definition

> A livelock is similar to a deadlock, except that the states of the
>   processes involved in the livelock constantly change with regard to
>   one another, none progressing.

Though it does fit the definition of deadlock

> In an operating system, a deadlock is a situation which occurs when a
>   process or thread enters a waiting state because a resource requested
>   is being held by another waiting process, which in turn is waiting for
>   another resource. If a process is unable to change its state
>   indefinitely because the resources requested by it are being used by
>   another waiting process, then the system is said to be in a deadlock.

Your first thread has the lock for `obj1`, the second has the lock of `obj2`, they then requests the other's lock and block.

Answer (score 1):

After checking the thread *states*, I`m now sure that it is a **deadlock!**

I stored the threads in locals `t1` and `t2` in order to call the `getState()` method.

The `System.out.println(t*.getState())` called right after starting the threads, prints: **TIMED_WAITING**.

The same in the `display` method **AFTER** the `Thread.sleep(5)`, prints: **RUNNABLE**

And now the key part:

Calling `System.out.println(t*.getState())` (for both threads `t1` and `t2`) in `main` again but this time after a `sleep(5000)` will print **BLOCKED**.

Blocked means: waiting for acquiring lock, and that means it is a **DEADLOCK!**

Answer (score 0):

Here's how each thread works:

1. Obtain a lock on one object - happens in the `run` method of the thread because `Counter.display` is `synchronized`.
2. Call it's `display` method.
3. Obtain a lock on the other object - preparing to call the `increment` method of the *other* object because the `increment` method is `synchronized`.
4. Call the *other* increment and ask it to increment its own object - strange, but does not contribute to the deadlock.

Apart from the issue of not setting `i` volatile because it could be accessed in a multi-threaded fashion there are a number of lock-related problems here but the main one is:

**The lock held in step `1` is not released before the lock is requested by stage `3`**. To me that is a **potential** deadlock because both threads will lock if they both pass stage `1` before the other hits `3`. However, as it is possible for the two threads to actually work fine so long as they never hit that then it **may** be possible to interpret this as a livelock as the two threads can happily run together for some time before they eventually deadly embrace.

So I would call this **potential deadlock** and let the pedants decide what to call it.

Comment: Thank you, I agree with you!

Answer (score 0):

Ran above program and got the thread dump 
for first thread

```
"first@573" prio=5 tid=0xb nid=NA waiting for monitor entry
  java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED
     blocks second@575
     waiting for second@575 to release lock on <0x245> (a dp.Counter)
      at dp.Counter.increment(LiveLock.java:44)
      at dp.Counter.display(LiveLock.java:37)
      - locked <0x246> (a dp.Counter)
      at dp.LiveLock.lambda$main$0(LiveLock.java:15)
      at dp.LiveLock$$Lambda$1.16460856.run(Unknown Source:-1)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

and for  second thread

```
"second@575" prio=5 tid=0xc nid=NA waiting for monitor entry
  java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED
     blocks first@573
     waiting for first@573 to release lock on <0x246> (a dp.Counter)
      at dp.Counter.increment(LiveLock.java:44)
      at dp.Counter.display(LiveLock.java:37)
      - locked <0x245> (a dp.Counter)
      at dp.LiveLock.lambda$main$1(LiveLock.java:20)
      at dp.LiveLock$$Lambda$2.23661220.run(Unknown Source:-1)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

looks like deadlock situation.